# Grupoids - congruencies and homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Proof that grupoid G = G(*) has only trivial congruencies <=> 
For every grupoid G' and every homomorphism f: G -> G' applies that f is injective or |f(G)| = 1.

My solution is the following:

(=>)
So we have only trivial congruencies on G and we want to proof that every homomorphism f: G -> G' is either injective or |f(G)| = 1

I am using a fact that (a CONGRUENT b) <=> (f(a) = f(b))

According to this theorem all those congruencies belong to ker(f).
While having only trivial congurencies this means identity and GxG, so we proof this for those two separately.

id.: 
(a,a) belong to ker(f)
(b,b) belong to ker(f)
etc.

Every element from G is going to itself on G'
(otherwise there would be a conflict with the definition of kernel. 
There would have to exist (a,b) belonging to ker(f), but that is not possible since we have an identity)
So its injective. - OK

GxG:
(a,a) belong to ker(f)
(a,b) belong to ker(f)
etc.

We use this fact about kernels 
ker(f) = {(a, b) belonging to G | f(a) = f(b)}

This means that every element is going to transform into one common element
( 
(a, a) : f(a) = f(a) = z
(a, b) : f(a) = f(b) = z
(a, c) : f(a) = f(c) = z
(b, a) : f(b) = f(a) = z
(b, b) : f(b) = f(b) = z
...
)

Ergo: |f(G)| = 1 - OK

Now from the other side

(<=)
So we say that for every grupoid G' and every homomorphism f: G -> G' for which applies that f is injective or |f(G)| = 1 applies 
that G must have only trivial congruencies.

For conflict we assume that G has a nontrivial congruency (such that its not either identity nor GxG).
Then there must also exist (a,b) belonging to a wanted congruency and therefore: (a,b) belongs to ker(f) and f(a) = f(b).
Which is in conflict with the fact that f should be injective.

For |f(G)| = 1, lets just take another pair (c,d) that may be in this nontrivial congruency.
( a != b != c != d, and there is no congruency relation betweet ab and cd).
So now (c,d) also belongs to ker(f). But that would mean that |f(G)| != 1 which is also in conflict with presumption that |f(G)| = 1.

Therefore G has to contain trivial congruencies only.

Is it OK? 
Also I am using theorem which is defined for groups and not grupoids. 
(a CONGRUENT b) <=> (f(a) = f(b))
Can it be easily extended for this case or should a different aproach be taken? 
(if so, please show)